# Filter Hugo Pagination by Custom Param

Tags: go, templates, pagination, blogs, hugo

### UPDATE

refering to **Oleg Butuzov** answer i can solve my first problem with :

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where .Site.RegularPages ".Params.yt" ">" "") 1 }}
```

but i have new problem that its listing all post on content folder Hugo that contain param "yt", and then i solve my problem from Official Hugo Discusion here  https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/complex-where-filter-using-and-or-not/5758/3 from **@bep** reply.

and here.. how to filtering where HUGO  with two condition :

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where (where .Site.RegularPages ".Params.yt" ">" "") ".Params.type" "post") 1 }}
```

**i update and clearing this Question because its realy hard to find about this Hugo Question and i hope its can solve your problem too.. thx :)**

**======= ORIGINAL QUESTION ======**

how to filter "where" for Variable $Paginator to only listing post that contain Custom param "yt"?

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where .Site.RegularPages "Type" "post") 2 }}
{{ range $paginator.Pages }}
   {{ .Params.yt }}
{{ end }}

{{ template "_internal/pagination.html" . }}
```

my Hugo Template structure :

conten/Post/
---- post1.md
---- post2.md

theme/layout/post/gameplay.html

then

```
post1.md

---
Title: Title 1
type: post
yt: ytchannelid
---

post2.md

---
Title: Tile 2
type: post
---

thanks before :)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of `.Params` and comparison operators.

So, for example, I want to show the only projects with forks on the project page.

```
{{ define "content" }}
  {{ range first 6 (where .Paginator.Pages ".Params.Forks" ">" "") }}
    <div class="inner">
    <pre>[{{.Params.Forks}}]</pre>
    <hr>
    </div>
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

- see more at [where](https://gohugo.io/functions/where/) manual page.

Comment: thanks thats work for me but i add more than one Where condition so this my final coding : 

{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where (where .Site.RegularPages ".Params.yt" ">" "") ".Params.type" "post") 1 }} 

thx :)

Comment: Pick, it as an answer so other people can go for the solution looking for a similar topic.